# robot programming with lisp?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, lisp, robotics

I'm looking for some examples of robot/AI programming using lisp. Are there any good online examples available anywhere (preferably not too academic in nature)?

Comment: @Joe lisp is very commonly used for AI programming

Comment: (((((O)) (R((L()()))()(Y))?(( x)((DD)))D(D)!((!!)!()()()))?

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner: Have you ever written any Lisp?  There are several beautiful, powerful Lisps, and you shouldn't ridicule what you obviously don't understand.  Also, your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/hungarian-lisp-developer-walks-away-with-google-ai-contest/2131 - apparently not only people use lisp for AI programming but also win big AI competitions with lisp.

Comment: The Robot Operating System (ROS) has a client library, roslisp, for writing "ROS nodes" (i.e. packages for a ROS robot system) in Common Lisp. This may be something you may want to explore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XS Lisp on Lego Mindstorms: http://www.xslisp.com/ilc03.pdf
There are multiple references online on Clojure and Lego Mindstorms dealing with a Clojure API for Lego Mindstorms.  In fact Lisp (in some form) and Leog Mindstorms's seems not uncommon: here's a AAAI paper on Lisp and Mindstorms with some code with a decided AI education approach: "Lauching into AI's October Sky with Robotics and Lisp" : http://www.aaai.org/ojs/index.php/aimagazine/article/viewArticle/1863

A Robotics Society of Southern California intro to Lisp may have source/examples on other pages: http://rssc.org/content/introduction-lisp

Aside from something like Mindstorms almost all robotic systems are custom corporate and/or university projects so you are likely to have to see if any final project results have published source.  There may also be university examples for robotics classes.

If you are looking for general AI programming then there are numerous references: Norvig's "Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming: Case Studies in Common Lisp" is a good starting point.

Comment: Already trying to work my way through PAIP. It's pretty slow going for a lisp newbie.

Comment: Really?  Have you worked through Chapters 1-3?  They are a pretty good albeit brief into to Lisp.  I don't have many other Lisp recommendations as I've been using the language off and on for a long time.  Most of the other texts have issues when introducing Lisp (they either just introduce Lisp or they focus on AI so PAIP is more 20-80% as far as that goes).  You could try SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) although it's Scheme.

Comment: SICP is a great book but doesn't really cover AI problems. It's best parts are on Lisp interpretation.

I have often read _Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach_ (AIMA) being cited as "the" intro to AI book, and there is Common Lisp code from the book available here: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/doc/overview.html

I'm not sure which edition this is from as I haven't actually read it, I think they did switch to Python or something in a later edition (3rd?)

Comment: I initially found the intro to CL in PAIP to be really dense, and needed more explanation on a lot of topics. The sample programs in PAIP are pretty interesting, but it's hard to tell how to see how any of the techniques in there can be applied to robotics problems like navigation and pathfinding.

Comment: It's true PAIP gets you going on basic AI.  From memory you should be able to apply it to pathfinding (well in simulations).  I think you'll have to look in robotics class sources and see if anything pops up.  There is this gulf between hs and even college robotics and industrial and upperlevel robotics.  I would like to say that Rodney Brooks' stuff can point you in the right direction but there is little code in his papers.

Comment: @spacemanaki - they didn't switch to Python.  Norvig toyed with the idea though.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0669194735) is supposed to be among the bestest books on both Common LISP and AI Programming. Use it wisely.

Comment: interesting...how does this compare to PAIP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a group of enthusiasts using lisp to build robots.

http://www.roborealm.com/help/Leaf.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are a [Robot Operating System (ROS)](http://www.ros.org/about-ros/) user, you might find [CRAM: Cognitive Robot Abstract](http://cram-system.org/cram) ([ROS Wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp)) useful. Both links contain many tutorials and examples of real-world use cases.